# Sorting as much as possible: values can travel no more than k positions to their left

Tags: algorithm, sorting

> Given an array of length N and an integer K, sort the array as much as possible such that no element travels more than K positions to its left. An element however can travel as much as it likes to its right.
>
> Let's define sortedness as the number of disordered pairs, i.e.: sortedness(1,2,3) = 0 and sortedness(3,1,2) = 2.
>
> Clarification: If the first `k+1` items of the array are moved to the end of the array, the other ones should be considered moved k+1 positions to the left.

This is an interview question. I thought of using a bubble sort. The outer loop would run K times with a run-time of O(nk). The smallest integer would be the only integer shifted to the left K times. The other integers would be shifted to the left less than K times.

Is there a more efficient way to approach this problem?

Comment: Do they define what "as much as possible" means? Minimize the number of inversions given the restrictions to the problem?

Comment: @Bakuriu Let's define sortedness as the number of disordered pairs, ie: sortedness(1,2,3) = 0 and sortedness(3,1,2) = 1.

Comment: If I move the first `k+1` items of the array to the end of the array, should I consider the other ones have been moved `k+1` positions to the left or not?

Comment: The restriction is not really clear, as “traveling” in the sense of a sort algorithm isn’t really clearly defined and heavily depends on the sorting algorithm. Also in `a b c d`, I can make `d` the left-most item by moving it three to the left, or by moving `c`, `b`, and `a` one to the right each.

Comment: @Oriol If the first k+1 items of the array are moved to the end of the array, the other ones should be considered moved k+1 positions to the left.

Comment: @user6427842 sortedness(3,1,2) = 2, because (3,1) and (3,2).

Comment: @DaveGalvin Yes, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use a min heap to sort the list of n elements in O(n log k).

1. Add the first k+1 unsorted elements to the heap.
2. Repeat this step: pop off the min element from the heap. Add it to the end of the sorted list. add the next unsorted element to the heap.

Because the heap always has at most k+1 elements regardless of n, all heap operations are O(log k), and the total running time is O(n log k)

Why is this correct?

Suppose it isn't. Then for some inputs my algorithm gives non-optimal sorts. Let I be such an input, let A be the output of my algorithm on I, and let B be the optimal sort.

Let i be the first index where A and B disagree. Let x = A[i], y = B[i], and let j be the index of x in B.

I claim that swapping x and y in B improve the sortedness of B, which is a contradiction.

Because A and B are identical for positions before i, the same set of k+1 elements are eligible to go into position i for both. Because my algorithm chose x to be the min of those elements, we know that x is less than y. We also know j is greater than i.

What happens when we swap x and y in B?

First, note that the change in sortedness is unaffected by anything to the left of i or to the right of j, because their positions relative to both x and y are unchanged by the swap.

We know there are no elements between i and j that are less than x, because my sort chose the smallest available element. Therefore all elements between i and j are at least as large as x.

For each element between i and j equal to x, swapping x and y improves sortedness by 1 because we improve y relative to these elements and x is unaffected.

For each element between i and j greater than x, the sortedness of x relative to these is improved by 1, and in the worst case the sortedness of y relative to these is degraded by 1, so the net effect is at worst 0.

Furthermore, swapping x and y improves the sortedness of x relative to y by 1, so this swap strictly improves overall sortedness.

Contradiction.

Comment: This is for K=6 as elements will move at most 6 positions to the left.

Comment: Oops. Misremembered the original problem. Yes, for arbitrary n and k, the running time is O(n log k).

Comment: I suppose this is really O(n log min(n,k)) if we're being nitpicky.

Comment: Why does this algorithm minimise `sortedness` ? It is an *interview question*, the OP was expected to justify the code.

Comment: @fjardon I added a proof. Please let me know if you find it clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Naive approach**:

iterate the array from left to right.
For each position `i` we  consider a subarray from `i to i+k`. Then we have to get the minimum valued element in this subarray and swap the 1st element of this subarray with this element. 
 Now, go to position `i+1` and do the same.

**Optimized Approach**:

We can use [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to solve this. Using this data structure you can find the minimum value between any range of an array and also edit any data online in `O(logn)`. In your problem, we can get the solution array using following steps,

`arr[1]` = minimum value between position 1 to min(k,n), then edit this position with infinity
`arr[2]` = min value between position 1 to min(k+1,n), then edit this position with infinity
`arr[3]` = min value between position 1 to min(k+2,n), then edit this position with infinity
`arr[4]` = min value between position 1 to min(k+3,n), then edit this position with infinity
...
...
`arr[n]` = min value between position 1 to min(k+n,n), then edit this position with infinity

Overall complexity `O(nlogn)`

for example:

`given array = 5 3 4 7 8 2 1 0 and K = 2`

using this algorithm you will get the solution array as this:

`3 4 5 2 1 0 7 8` 
 `sortedness value = 12`

Hope it helps!

Best regards,
[Agassaa](http://Agassaa)

Comment: Why does this (greedy) algorithm produce the optimal result?

Comment: Both naive and optimized approach of my answer is same (can be proved). Do you have confusion with why naive approach works? If yes, then I'll explain it

Comment: Yes, please *prove* the naive version works. Show that it respects the constraints and the solution is optimal.

Comment: Given the array: `[100, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1]` and `K=4`, applying your algorithm would move `100` to the last position which is in contradiction with  the constraints of the problem.

Comment: How is it contradicting the constraints? the problem allows you to move an element any number of positions to the right but not left. (read the post again)

Comment: Agreed, but still I'd like to see the proof.

Comment: @PaulHankin the proof is quite observational, e.g. why you should put smallest element at first of a subarray. Do you have any contradiction case where it won't work? moreover, there is now a better answer (already has 2 votes) which also has no proof but of same solution. Can you ask him why it works?

Comment: @agassaa I added a proof to my answer.